# what is the best way to keep my php files with only php code's?

Tags: php, html

I have a file with php and html codes mixed, like this:

```
echo "<tr class='somthing'>";
```

What is the best way to keep my php files with only php code?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean - do you mean that you want the PHP and HTML code to be separated?

Comment: yeah, i have a file with php and html codes together

Comment: Most of the answers below are going to say to use a templating system. Just don't forget that PHP itself was a templating system that grew to be a complete language.

Comment: yeah, all this its because when the php code need to be encoded , i dont know if the html, on the middle, will become a problem to me. You know, zendencoder encode only php stuffs for exp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some contention about this, so I will simply say that whatever you choose, stick with it.

Generally, you can use a templating system (e.g., Smarty) to keep your files formally clean of PHP code, but this has some drawbacks in the speed department.

Alternatively, you can use minimal code by breaking out the display related portions and using small PHP snippets therein, e.g.

```
<?php foreach ($myArray as $myElement): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $myElement; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Of course this doesn't completely separate your code from your HTML, but that's nearly impossible to do for anything nontrivial; in my opinion, Smarty templates are just different code, not the absence of code.  This approach is advocated by some frameworks such as codeigniter and Zend Framework (thought you can use them with Smarty as well, it is not the default).

One important thing to remember is that your display logic is just that: logic.  Whatever method you choose, you will never be 100% free of code (or code-like markings which are interpreted by other code/applications) in the display until you use static-only displays.

Comment: Not only speed, but the learning curve involved in learning how to do it their way. That's what bugs me a bit about django as well (not that django is for php.. but you know).

Comment: I dont' know what kind of speed hits your talking about my pages load just fine i use the smarty caching and maybe that might make the difference and it really wasn't difficult for me to learn. but everybody is different

Answer (score 2):

You could go to a template engine like Smarty. This allows you to have a controller to prepare all your data, then pass it off to a view for rendering.

You can also do it yourself. You have a view that simply uses  or basic loops to echo out rows. Strict outputting, no other logic. Your controller prepares the data, then you can use output buffering to include the view, have it render, get the buffered output and echo it at a later point.

Answer (score 2):

It's good to keep "data" and "display" logic separate. One nice way of doing this is to use an architecture called Model, View, Controller (MVC)

Most PHP frameworks are built around the MVC. Have a look at Zend Framework or Codeignitor.

Answer (score 1):

use a templating engine such as [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

here is a  [list](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/) of others

Answer (score 1):

You should examine the MVC (model-view-controller) approach. MVC allows you to separate your business logic from your presentation logic (HTML).

For an overview of MVC, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

For a list of PHP frameworks that support MVC, see: http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to utilize a templating system like Smarty as others have mentioned. I wrote somewhat of an introduction to it in another question:

[Beginner's guide to making a template driven PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006506/beginners-guide-to-making-a-template-driven-php-site/6008293#6008293)

As you can see, it provides a great way to keep your HTML and PHP code separate